# .htaccess Get rules from an external file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, external

So is it possible to get values from an external file?

Eg.

values.php

```
echo 'Some rewrite rules';
```

Is it possible in any way?

I have heard about RewriteMap, but its not for .htaccess

Ps. If you could do some php code in .htaccess or get values from MySQL it would also fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

-Thanks

Comment: This is not directly possible and there are good reasons for that. It would lead to chaos. But nevertheless there are many possibilities, even to interact with external stuff like databases from .htaccess style files, but in a more indirect manner. You will have to elaborate in more depth what is really is you want to do. But usually what is done is this: .htaccess style files are rewritten (changed/recreated) to reflect new rule sets by the application which maintains those rules itself.

Comment: So I should edit the file with php?

Comment: I only said that is what is typically done, for example by CMS systems and the like. Whether that is what you "should do" is something else, that obviously depends on what you want to do.

Comment: It is a custom cms. I need to make rewrite rules for modules/plugins

Comment: @arkascha It is a cms, with plugin/modules.